# Popup appears after a second when hovered over an image

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an image that will instantly show a popup when mouse hovers over it but I want it to wait for a bit before it shows the popup but also have it so that when mouse moves away from the image in will not appear if it didn't already.

I think that the best way to do it is to use a timer that starts when Mouse enters the picture and gets discarded when the mouse leaves the picture.

```cs
private async void img_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)
    //when timer finished
    popup.IsOpen = true;
}

private void img_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Timer.Stop();
    popup.IsOpen = false;
}
```

Comment: Start a task that waits with Task.Delay then opens the popup. If mouse leaves, cancel the task with the cancellation token source.

Comment: A timer is not useful here, because its use case would be to execute some code repeatedly in a fixed interval. Use `Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))` instead and use a `CancellationToken` to cancel the `Task`, like aybe mentioned.

Comment: Can't you use a tool tip? It's simple to configure its delay.

Comment: https://wpf.2000things.com/2013/07/11/861-tooltip-delays-and-timing/